# Wordpress changing script source from https to http

Tags: https, http

added three links by request of a international shipping company. 
Added the code to the head.php doc in my theme folder.

Cleared the page cache and re-uploaded the theme cache. When I look at the source code the url has been changed to HTTP from HTTPS. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Just add 's' again?

Comment: the file is called out with https: but if you view source it is changed to http:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a plug-in "Wordpress HTTPS" it was forcing all but my woocommerse pages cart and checkout page to be http:. Woocommerse already has a setting to force Cart and Checkout page to be HTTPS so I really did not need the other plug-in, so I deactivated it. I then noticed that the pages were not being forced to be HTTPS. I ran https://www.whynopadlock.com/ and found 6 images in the header that were called with the http in front of the src=. I removed the http://www.thewebsite and that fixed the issue. now just my cart and checkout pages are https with a lock and the rest can be whatever i want.